# APScheduler shut down randomly

Tags: python, apscheduler

Scheduler running fine in production, then all of a sudden it shut down. Clearly DB might have been offline for a bit (web apps never missed a beat so it was transient).

Log reported...

```
[2019-11-25 07:59:14,907: INFO/ercscheduler] Scheduler has been shut down
[2019-11-25 07:59:14,908: DEBUG/ercscheduler] Looking for jobs to run
[2019-11-25 07:59:14,909: WARNING/ercscheduler] Error getting due jobs from job store 'default': (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Network is unreachable
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 6432?

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
[2019-11-25 07:59:14,909: DEBUG/ercscheduler] Next wakeup is due at 2019-11-25 13:59:24.908318+00:00 (in 10.000000 seconds)
[2019-11-25 07:59:14,909: INFO/ercscheduler] listener closed
[2019-11-25 07:59:14,909: INFO/ercscheduler] server has terminated
[2019-11-25 08:00:10,747: INFO/ercscheduler] Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
[2019-11-25 08:00:10,797: INFO/ercscheduler] Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
[2019-11-26 15:27:48,392: INFO/ercscheduler] Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
[2019-11-26 15:27:48,392: INFO/ercscheduler] Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
```

How do I make the scheduler more fault tolerant? I have to restart the daemon again to get it going.

Answer (score 6):

I found something very similar to your issue on the APScheduler Github repo.
https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/issues/109

### This issue here seems to be mitigated and merged in `version 3.3`.

All you have to do is upgrade to at least to `3.3`.
If you would like to **alter the default 10 seconds** interval then you have to set the `jobstore_retry_interval` when you create the scheduler instance.

### If you cannot upgrade, then i would try monkey patching the corresponding function in APScheduler.

```
def monkey_patched_process_jobs(self):

     # You have alter the way job processing done in this function.

     pass

# replacing the function with the patched one
BackgroundScheduler._process_jobs = monkey_patched_process_jobs

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
```

Keep in mind that this is not ideal, i would only do monkey patching if i am unable to upgrade due to breaking changes.

---

### How this functionality works under the hood

This is a snippet from the APScheduler Git repo

```
try:
    due_jobs = jobstore.get_due_jobs(now)
except Exception as e:
    # Schedule a wakeup at least in jobstore_retry_interval seconds
    self._logger.warning('Error getting due jobs from job store %r: %s',
                         jobstore_alias, e)
    retry_wakeup_time = now + timedelta(seconds=self.jobstore_retry_interval)
    if not next_wakeup_time or next_wakeup_time > retry_wakeup_time:
        next_wakeup_time = retry_wakeup_time

    continue
```

`self.jobstore_retry_interval` is set in the following manner:

```
self.jobstore_retry_interval = float(config.pop('jobstore_retry_interval', 10))
```

Comment: I would assume in the log I would see "Error getting due jobs from job store" if this was the case. Is it possible my postgres DB is offline for (say) more than 10 seconds and I am using the default or 10 seconds and it just stops processing.  I would want the scheduler to NEVER stop attempting to connect to postgres, so that unless the DB crashed the scheduler would restart.  Is this possible?